# how to save the satus of ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to shutdown the robot, and restart the robot ,I want to let the robot remember the status before he shutdown?
Any friends can help me?

If I can not save the status, I must move the robot to the start point by hand.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238197/how-to-save-the-satus-of-ros?/) by [ligang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26953/ligang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is impossible, simply because it is not clearly defined, what the status is or what the encompasses. This could be a massive amount of different things, settings, data, etc.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0